# C++ Function return value storing variable issue

Tags: c++, function, parameters, return

I'm trying to store *numofterms* with the return value from my *UserPrompt* function but it keeps looking for a string in addition to the double from the input parameters. Any way to fix this?

```
const string PROGDESCRIPTION = "Program will approximate the natural logarithm of 2 ";

double UserPrompt(string prompt, double terms)
{


    cout << prompt;
    cin >> terms;

    while(terms <= 0)
    {
        cout << "ERROR - Input must be positive and non-zero! Please Try again. ";
    }
    return terms;
}
int main()
{

double numofterms;

cout << PROGDESCRIPTION << endl << endl << endl;

UserPrompt("Enter the number of terms to compute: ", numofterms); 

numofterms = UserPrompt(numofterms); 
cout << numofterms;

}
```

Comment: Well, the function takes a string, so you need to pass a string when you call it. What exactly is the question then?

Comment: I see no sense in passing `terms` *at all* to that function, and the second call is obviously wrong.

Comment: There are several more calls to the function throughout the program that are made, only posted this bit, but thanks for your input bud.

Comment: There are a couple of issues with your code. On the main you are calling UserPrompt("Enter the number of terms to compute: ", numofterms); without assigning this function a temporary double variable that will store its return value. Another problem is that, you are also calling the function UserPrompt(numofterms); with only one parameter. However the function UserPrompt takes two arguments and not one and so you are missing the string arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
double UserPrompt(string prompt, double terms)
{
```

To this:

```
double UserPrompt(string prompt)
{
    double terms;
```

And this:

```
UserPrompt("Enter the number of terms to compute: ", numofterms);
numofterms = UserPrompt(numofterms);
```

To this:

```
numofterms = UserPrompt("Enter the number of terms to compute: ");
```

Comment: @joe: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the V next to it.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that C++ doesn't like you passing literals in the function. So do something like

```
char prompt[101] = "Enter the number of terms to compute: ";

UserPrompt(prompt, numofterms);
```

I don't like the string function, so I'm using a character array. I'll work either way. I'm not sure if strings are passed by reference automatically like character arrays are, though.

Comment: Im unsure telling OP to use char array instead of strings is really good advice. Const will probably fix your problem with the literals.

Comment: I suppose that's my university C++ mannerisms coming out. We use c-strings exclusively since 1) They're a part of the C++ spec whereas string is an add-on and 2) It's just good to practice creating, passing, and accessing elements of arrays. But yeah, I assume it is true that many (most?) people probably just use strings.

Also, yes, const, good point. Thanks!